# How to add attachments in SOAP request using xml?

Tags: python-3.x, soap, python-requests

```
    strXml ="""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
      <soap12:Body>
        <SMTPEmail xmlns="http://www.test.com/123">
          <ID></ID>
          <EmailAddress>myname@company.com</EmailAddress>
          <To>myname@company.com</To>
          <CC>myname@company.com</CC>
          <BCC></BCC>
          <Subj>hello</Subj>
          <Text>hello</Text>
          <IsBodyHtml>hello</IsBodyHtml>
          <Server></Server>
          <Debug>string</Debug>
          <GUID>{12344-3434-34334-3434343-65656565h5h}</GUID>
          <Attachments></Attachments>
          <RelayCount>0</RelayCount>
        </SMTPEmail>
      </soap12:Body>
    </soap12:Envelope>"""

response = requests.post(url,data=strXml, headers=header)
print(response.content)
```

I am able to get this to work to send a message but I can't figure out how to insert my file path (example: 'C:\Users\name\Downloads\test1.xlsx') inside the **Attachments** tag to get it to attach to the email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I needed to convert my file to hexadecimal like this:

```
import binascii

def fileAttachmentHex(filepath):

    file = open(filepath,'rb').read()
    file_encode = binascii.hexlify(file)
    return file_encode.decode('utf-8')
```

And then insert the output of the hex code inside the attachment tag with the file name like this:

```
<Attachments>test1.xlsx:GSDBSG0033043H3G0000000000000</Attachments>
```